# SQL Query: Gathering users from 3 different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am new to SQL and stackoverflow, but I was hoping someone could help me out with the following problem.

There are three different databases for a company, each of which represents a different division within the company.

Each database contains employee information in the employee table: 
id, first name, last name, division.

There are three divisions. Each employee can be in more than one division. The id is unique to the employee; an employee in multiple divisions has the same id in each table.

How can I write a query that selects each unique employee and the divisions that they work in (in one row)?

My results from the following code is incomplete, meaning that there are a few missing employees that are unaccounted for.

```
Insert into #temp1 (id, first name, last name, division AS divison1) from     db1.table WHERE active_flag = 1 AND termination_date IS NULL
Insert into #temp2 (id, first name, last name, division AS division2) from db2.table WHERE active_flag = 1 AND termination_date IS NULL
Insert into #temp3 (id, first name, last name, division AS division3) from   db3.table WHERE active_flag = 1 AND termination_date IS NULL

Insert into #uniqueids (id, first name, last name)
SELECT id, first name, last name FROM #temp1 
 UNION SELECT id, first name, last name FROM #temp2
 UNION SELECT id, first name, last name FROM #temp3

SELECT #uniqueids.id, #uniqueids.first name, #uniqueids.last name,
division1+division2+division3 AS divisions
FROM #uniqueids 
LEFT JOIN #temp1 ON #uniqueids.id=#temp1.id 
LEFT JOIN #temp2 ON #uniqueids.id=#temp2.id
LEFT JOIN #temp3 ON #uniqueids.id=#temp3.id
WHERE #uniqueids.id NOT LIKE '%default%' AND #uniqueids.id NOT LIKE 'S%'
```

*** I edited the code to make it more clear

I know that certain employees are unaccounted for because I was given a result set that has a list of 778 unique employees. 
   Example row: 
   [id, first name, last name, divisions]
   [asd1234, Julie, Wong, 1 2 3]

The results of inserting into and selecting the #uniqueids displaying 900 employees, due to the existence of ids that contain "default" and starting with "S", which do not count. These are addressed in the last section of the code, which I have just now included.

My current result set has 770 unique employees after running the entire query, which means that I am missing 8.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Are they unaccounted for in `#uniqueids`?

Comment: Do you mean the employees are missing or just the division names are missing for some employees? And what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Hi, I added some more information that may help. I believe that there are some employees that are excluded, not certain divisions that they may be a part of.

Comment: I'd double check your employee count first. Don't assume that the result set you were given is correct. Perhaps there were inserts and/or deletions since it was given to you. Do a `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)` on your data set of joined IDs, or just LEFT JOIN each database.schema.table on the ID to ensure you get an accurate count.